# SwipeCellKit Crash happened when reload tableview after delete cell

Tags: ios, swift

I want to update my view after SwipeCell did it's delete action, and it crashed here:

```
func swipeController(_ controller: SwipeController, didDeleteSwipeableAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView?.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Crash Info:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update'
```

Here is my sample code. I know it did some animation things inside framework. Is there any delegate function to call and safety update my tableview? Please tell me, great thanks

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
 let delete = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { action, indexPath in
        // want to reload tableview here
     }
     delete.hidesWhenSelected = true
     configure(action: delete, with: .trash)
     return [delete]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) {
 // or here
}
```

Comment: Show the error. You probably just need to update your data source.

Comment: @Don Yes, you're all correct, but my question is what is the right timing to update tableview in SwipeCell.framework After delete some row? I didn't search out in their docs